# List<Base> to List<Long> ... conditional cast

Tags: lambda, java-8, type-conversion, java-stream, predicate

Lets say I have those 3 classes (strongly reduced) :

```
public interface Base
{
    String getType();
}

public class Object1 implements Base
{
    String getType() { ... };

    long getSerialNr() { ... };
}

public class Object2 implements Base
{
    String getType() { ... };

    long getPartNr() { ... };
}
```

How would I (using Java 8 streams) convert a `List<Base>` to a `List<Long>` using conditional casts? I started with this:

```
List<Long> result = baseList.stream().filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .filter(Object1.class::isInstance)
    .map(Object1.class::cast)
    .map(o -> o.getSerialNr())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

...but how can I integrate the second case, where the element is an instance of `Object2` and I want to return `getPartNr`?

Comment: Why not simply declaring `long getId()` in the `Base` interface?

Comment: Thats unfortunately not possible. Thats just an oversimplified example of my "real world problem" where it makes sense to not have getId() in the interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the number of classes may grow, you may have to abstract the mapping of type to property:

```
static Map<Predicate<Base>,Function<Base,Long>> ACCESSORS;
static {
    Map<Predicate<Base>,Function<Base,Long>> m=new HashMap<>();
    m.put(Object1.class::isInstance, base -> ((Object1)base).getSerialNr());
    m.put(Object2.class::isInstance, base -> ((Object2)base).getPartNr());
    ACCESSORS=Collections.unmodifiableMap(m);
}
static Stream<Long> get(Base b) {
    return ACCESSORS.entrySet().stream()
            .filter(e -> e.getKey().test(b))
            .map(e -> e.getValue().apply(b));
}
```

The `get` method assumes that the predicates are mutual exclusive, which is the case when testing for these non-`interface` types.

Then, you can use it like:

```
List<Long> result = baseList.stream()
    .flatMap(YourClass::get)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You could also inline the `get` method, but that’s not improving the readability:

```
List<Long> result = baseList.stream()
    .flatMap(b -> ACCESSORS.entrySet().stream()
        .filter(e -> e.getKey().test(b))
        .map(e -> e.getValue().apply(b)))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, there's no point in the interface Base if there won't be a common method in there which all classes should implement. IF you want to do it that way then it's not gonna be nice. You should change your code to the below which should do the trick:

```
List<Long> aList = baseList.stream().filter((Objects::nonNull)
        .filter(obj->(obj instanceof Object1 || obj instanceof Object2))
        .map(num-> (num instanceof Object1) ? ((Object1) num).getPratNr() : ((Object2) num).getPratNr())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: The example was strongly reduced to the core problem... I wouldn't use an interface with no methods shared between the implementations of course. Thanks for that snippet!

Comment: The other posted solutions to this problem are to complex. This is the simplest and most direct solution which makes it preferable to the others.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to group the baseList by its elements class.

```
public class MyTest {

  @Test
  public void java8_listbase_to_listlong_conditional_cast() {
    List<Base> baseList = new ArrayList<>();
    baseList.add(new Object1());
    baseList.add(new Object2());

    Map<?, List<Base>> group = baseList.stream()
      .filter(Objects::nonNull)
      .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(key -> key.getClass()));

    Stream<Long> object1stream = group.get(Object1.class)
      .stream()
      .map(Object1.class::cast)
      .map(Object1::getSerialNr);

    Stream<Long> object2stream = group.get(Object2.class)
      .stream()
      .map(Object2.class::cast)
      .map(Object2::getPartNr);

    List<Long> longList = Stream.concat(object1stream, object2stream).collect(Collectors.toList());

    assertArrayEquals(new Long[] {0l, 1l}, longList.toArray());
  }



  public interface Base {
  }

  public class Object1 implements Base {
    long getSerialNr() { return 0L; };
  }

  public class Object2 implements Base {
    long getPartNr() { return 1L; };
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I wanted a List of Long values instead of a Map with 2 entries (resp. 2 separated lists).

Comment: ok, i have updated the example. You can inline the intermediate results to get one operation but the readability suffers.

Comment: Thank you! Now thats the third possibility to get the desired result. I just started using the Java8 stream api and I think about how much the performance impact is between those 3 answers in this thread. It's all nice to read instead of the good old for(...) loop, but I think it's much slower, isn't it?

Comment: you can search for benchmarks for the different loop speeds. streams are getting faster with newer java release. do not prematurely micro optimize your code if readability suffers and when you do not have a performance problem. never assume but measure performance.

Comment: Thanks, I will consider that!